# How can I enable smooth-scrolling?

Tags: 11.10, unity

How can I enable smoothscrolling?
With the Mac, this looks much smoother and with Windows I use the program smoothscroll which gives the same experience.
I mean smoothscrolling everywhere, not the fake-smoothscrolling by firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion from some months ago that addresses the same question. [Are there plans for system-wide smooth scrolling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39435/are-there-plans-for-system-wide-smooth-scrolling)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Real smooth-scrolling (if you mean pixel-based instead of scroll-a-few lines) was introduced in 12.04, and I don't think 11.10 had that. If you upgrade 12.04 or 12.10 any GTK3 based apps (such as Nautilus) should have smooth-scrolling.